# Modify array in place while using .filter and .forEach

Tags: javascript, arrays

I would like to filter an array of objects and update some value on the filtered entries. Here is my original code, without filtering:

```js
let obj = {
  foo: [
    {
      bar: "I should be modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I should not be modified",
      modify: false,
    },{
      bar: "I should be modified",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
};

obj.foo.forEach((item, i) => {
  let newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
  newItem.bar = "I have been modified";
  obj.foo[i] = newItem;
});

console.log(obj.foo);
/* Output:
  [
    {
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: false,
    },{
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
*/
```

Now I would like to replace `.forEach(...` with `.filter(e => e.modify).forEach(...`. So instead of modifying all the elements of `obj.foo`, only those with `modify === true` are modified. How can this be done without filtering again inside the forEach loop?

```js
obj.foo.filter(e => e.modify).forEach((item, i) => {
  let newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
  newItem.bar = "I have been modified";
  obj.foo[i] = newItem; // will not work as the index i is not correct from the original array
});

console.log(obj.foo);

/* Expected output:
  [
    {
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I should not be modified",
      modify: false,
    },{
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
*/

/* Actual output:
  [
    {
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I have been modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I should be modified",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
*/
```

Comment: What is the expected output here? If you filter modify , how will you change the bar property?

Comment: I think you wouldn't have to filter again in the forEach loop regardless. What's wrong with adding `.filter(e => e.modify).forEach(...`?

Comment: obj.foo.filter((item, i) => {
if(item.modify === true) {
what ever you want to change goes here;
return item;
}
});

Comment: If you use the `filter` method you will lose the correct index of the element. So without filtering you should be checking with an `if` statement inside the `forEach` callback.

Comment: @eldar I was hoping to avoid a massive if statement but yes that would work

Comment: you should first map it then filter with the mapped index... also, please provide your output

Comment: You could clean this up quite a bit `obj.foo = obj.foo.map(item => item.modify ? {...item, bar: "I have been modified"}: item)`

Answer (score 1):

```js
let obj = {
  foo: [
    {
      bar: "baz",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "bad",
      modify: false,
    },{
      bar: "hello",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
};

const {foo} = obj;

const t = foo.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (curr.modify) {
    curr.bar = "I have been modified";
    acc.push(curr);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(t)
```

Comment: You have a bug I think, `acc.push(curr)` should be outside the if statement.

Comment: Yes, if you don't need to filter the array by "modify" prop

Answer (score 0):

This can also be done like this:

```
obj.foo.filter(e => e.modify).map((item) => {
  item.bar = "I have been modified"
});
```

I think this should help.

Answer (score 0):

So after read all the comments, that you don't want if-statement in it and other things, then this idea comes to my mind, without changing too much of your code, why don't let each item takes it's own original index, after modified, delete the idx property:

```js
let obj = {
  foo: [
    {
      bar: "I should be modified",
      modify: true,
    },{
      bar: "I should not be modified",
      modify: false,
    },{
      bar: "I should be modified",
      modify: true,
    },
  ],
};
let index = 0;

obj.foo.filter(e =>  ++index && e.modify && (e.idx = index)).forEach((item, i) => {
  let newItem = Object.assign({}, item);
  newItem.bar = "I have been modified";
  obj.foo[newItem.idx - 1] = newItem; 
  delete newItem.idx;
});

console.log(obj.foo);
```